# problem in scanning character in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
  int a,b,c;
  char ch;
  printf("Enter value of a and b");
  scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
  printf("Enter choice of operation");
  scanf("%c",&ch);// **Here this statment is not able to receive my input***
  switch(ch)
  {
     case '+':
            c=a+b;
            break;
     case '-':
            c=a-b;
            break;

     default:
             printf("invalid");
             break;
  }
getch();
}
```

Error:

`scanf("%c",&ch);` // **Here this statment is not able to receive my input**
Unable to scan input given by user??????

thanks..

Answer (score 9):

Unlike most conversions, `%c` does *not* skip whitespace before converting a character. After the user enters the two numbers, a carriage return/new-line is left in the input buffer waiting to be read -- so that's what the `%c` reads.

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &ch)` would fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Just try 
`scanf(" %c", &ch);`
This is because your scanf is treating the whitespace after the second number as the character to be inserted into ch.

Answer (score 4):

It's getting the newline character from your previous data entry.  Look into using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` instead of using `scanf()` directly.

Answer (score 4):

Here in this statement write `%s` instead of `%c`. It will surely work.

```
scanf("%s",&ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

in this problem you can write like this
scanf(" %c",&ch);

a space will cover your "Enter" character,then it scan's the input that you want...https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/ANGPHrqeAq

Answer (score 1):

If you're just reading in a single character, you could just use `getchar()` -

```
 c = getchar();
```

Answer (score 1):

For a single character input, use `getchar()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getchar()` or `sscanf()` whichever comforts more.

Like

```
char ch;

ch = getchar();
```

This is simple. also if you want to use `scanf("%c",&ch);` then,
just remove the `\n` from your previous `printf()` statement.