# scanf and no switch case is executed

Tags: c

New bee in C. This is my code (It replaces a character from a string):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() 
{
    char str[100], r, ra;
    printf("enter string");
    gets(str);
    int length;
    length= strlen(str);
    printf("length of string is %d",length);
    printf("\nenter the the character that will replace");
    scanf("%c",&r);
    printf("where to replace\n b...begning\ne....ending\np....position");
    scanf("%c",&ra);
    int pos;
    switch(ra)
    {
    case 'b' : str[1]=r; break;
    case 'e' : str[length-1] = r; break;
    case 'p' : printf("enter position");
               scanf("%d",pos);
               if(pos<1 || pos>length-1)
                    printf("please enter a position between 1 and %d",length-1);
               else
                    str[pos]= r;
               break;
    }
    printf("\n after replacing string is  %s", str);  
    getche();

}
```

The problem is that the IDE is not compiling this part of the program, I know that I am doing some thing wrong, but can't figure out what? Need help please.

```
    scanf("%c",&ra);
    int pos;
    switch(ra)
    {
    case 'b' : str[1]=r; break;
    case 'e' : str[length-1] = r; break;
    case 'p' : printf("enter position");
               scanf("%d",pos);
               if(pos<1 || pos>length-1)
                    printf("please enter a position between 1 and %d",length-1);
               else
                    str[pos]= r;
               break;
    }
```

Comment: "the ide is not compiling this part of the program":  What do you mean by that?  It gives an error message?  Something else?  Please share that with us.

Comment: I guess you are using Visual Studio, is that correct? And don't use `gets()`, it's dangerous. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Suspecting the compiler "not to compile" part of your program is not very productive. This is certainly not what you have observed. You observed that the program executes none of the cases that you programmed. There would have been an easy way to know where execution goes, there: add a `default` case and print out what you have in `ra` at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `scanf(" %c",&ra)` insted of `"%c"`. Because reading with `"%c"`  give you a garbage value in `ra`.And that value is new line.

When you enter value in `a` you press something like `p` and then  `Enter key`. This `Enter key` still remains in `stdin` stream.

Next time when you read in `ra` then the `Enter key` in `stdin` stream is returned in `ra`.

So for removing that `Enter key` you need to read like `" %c"`.

Comment: True, but the OP's question is the program doesn't compile yet. He'll encounter this problem after he can compile and run it.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf(" %c", &ra);` // space before %c

 Unlike most conversions, `%c` does not skip whitespace before converting a character. After the user enters the number, a carriage return/new-line is left in the input buffer waiting to be read -- so that's what the %c reads.. [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109512/problem-in-scanning-character-in-c)

And for the same reason your switch case is not working, since `ra` does not have the expected value

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is that the ide is not compiling this part of the program

Well, that's a strong accusation. Rather than assume that the compiler does decide not to compile part of the code (on a whim), it's a safer bet that your program's execution flow just does not enter that part as you expected.

In particular, `scanf` does not behave as you think it does. It reads from `stdin`, which is a buffered input stream. "Buffered" means that it does not provide your program with input until a newline in read, i.e. until the user presses return. But the `scanf` family of functions doesn't look for new lines, it treats the new-line character as a normal character. In your case, scanning `"%c"` tries to read any character from the input. The subsequent `"%c"` then reads the new line, so `&ra` really is `'\n'` in your switch statement.

I usually find working with direct input from the user difficult in C, but if you must prompt the user interactively, I suggest that you read in a whole line of input first with `fgets` and then analyse that line with `sscanf`. That gets rid of the seemingly out-of-sync input and also allows you to scan a line several times, perhaps for alternative input syntaxes.

So, here's a version of your code that uses this technique:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    char str[100], r, ra;
    char line[20];
    int length;
    int pos;

    printf("enter string");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);   // note: str includes trailing newline

    length = strlen(str);

    printf("length of string is %d\n", length);
    printf("enter the the character that will replace:\n");
    fgets(line, 20, stdin);
    sscanf(line, " %c ",&r);

    printf("where to replace\n");
    printf("b...begning\ne....ending\np....position\n");
    fgets(line, 20, stdin);
    sscanf(line, " %c ", &ra);

    switch (ra)
    {
    case 'b':   str[1] = r; 
                break;

    case 'e':   str[length - 1] = r; 
                break;

    case 'p':   printf("enter position");
                fgets(line, 20, stdin);
                sscanf(line, "%d ", &pos);

                if(pos < 1 || pos > length-1)
                    printf("please enter a position between 1 and %d",
                        length-1);
                else
                    str[pos]= r; break;
    }

    printf("after replacing string is %s", str);  

    return 0;
}
```

There are still problems with your code, mainly to do with zero-based array indexing in C. I leave it to you to sort those out. Also, prefer the safer `fgets(buf, len, stdin)` over `gets(str)`, which does not prevent buffer overflow. And your query for a position should take a pointer to the address of `pos`, not just `pos`. And please make a habit of putting the new-line character last in your `printf` strings. It makes for cleaner reading and matches the way that the buffered output stream works.

Answer (score 0):

The program doesn't compile, the most likely reason is that you are using a compiler that supports C89 only (I guess it's Visual Studio), or you are using C89 mode.

In this code:

```
scanf("%c",&ra);
int pos;
switch(ra)
{
```

the variable `pos` is defined in the middle of a block, which is supported only since C99. The solution is to move all definitions up to the beginning of a block:

```
int main() 
{
    char str[100], r, ra;
    int pos;
    printf("enter string");
```

Use `fgets()` to replace `gets()`, use `int main` to replace `void main`. And fix the problem with using `scanf` that is covered by the other answers.