# numerical representation of the characters

Tags: c

So,here is my question.I read in k&R that a character is internally represented as a number.So just to check i tried out these two programes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num;
    char cht;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    scanf("%c",&cht);
    if(num==cht)
        printf("they are same\n");
    else
        printf("they are not same\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

When i run this program.For the input num as same as the ascii value of cht,still it shows "they are not same".

But for this program it worked.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int num;
     scanf("%d",&num);
     if(num=='A')
        printf("they are same\n");
     else
        printf("they are not same\n");
     return 0;
}
```

Here if i give num=65,it works.My question is why it is different in both the cases?

Comment: this code worked? you gave two inputs with `scanf("%c",&cht);` in there? how?

Comment: This worked for me! (Maybe add a space there: `scanf(" %c",&cht);`)

Comment: @Rizier123 that's what i meant . :-)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5109512/3933332

Comment: **Always** check the return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with

```
scanf("%c",&cht);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c",&cht);
```

When you enter the integer and press enter that is there in the buffer you need to consume it with placing a space before `%c`. Both the code will work ASCII value matches the character.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, `cht` doesn't get the <kbd>A</kbd> you pressed, but instead gets the new line character from <kbd>ENTER</kbd> you pressed after inputting <kbd>65</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code, add a leading space  while scanning for *character*. It will *eat* the previous <kbd>ENTER</kbd> [`\n`], otherwise, it will read the leftover `\n` which is a valid input for `%c`.

Adding a leading [] will tell the `scanf()` to ignore all the leading *whitespace* family character and read the first non-whitespace one.

Without that [] before `%c`, what your program is getting is `\n` for `cht`.